# Any way to set up Cmd-Tab to cycle among apps and Chrome browser tabs on OS X?

Tags: macos, google-chrome

On my Mac, I commonly use a mix of native apps (like Excel) and webapps (like Google Docs) in Chrome. Is there any way to get Cmd-Tab to cycle through the apps and webapps one at a time, instead of treating Chrome as a single app?

Answer (score 2):

After a long search, I found [HyperSwitch](http://bahoom.com/hyperswitch) which lets me alt-tab between chrome windows. This works for chrome apps or separate chrome windows.

Comment: Thanks, just tried it but it doesn't treat Chrome tabs as separate windows, so it doesn't fit the bill, but it's still a cool utility.

Comment: Right. But it does work between multiple chrome windows. So, you could open up Gmail, Google Docs, Gdrive, etc. each in its own chrome window. This is what I do.

Comment: Is hyper switch buggy for you too or is it just me? It crashes a lot and it cant handle situation when you want to switch between fullscreen and standard app.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any easy way I can think of, but you can create a site-specific browser for certain web apps, using [Fluid](http://fluidapp.com/).

> Web applications like Gmail, Facebook, Campfire and Pandora are becoming more and more like desktop applications every day. Running each of these web apps in a separate tab in your browser can be a real pain.
>
> Fluid lets you create a Real Mac App (or "Fluid App") out of any website or web application, effectively turning your favorite web apps into OS X desktop apps.

In essence, you'll get a separate application for each of your web apps.